# Safety: Win10/7 dual boot vs. separate drives

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, security, multi-boot

**Question**:
I was wondering about the safety, feasibility and convenience of using a standard dual boot setup vs. separately installing 2 OSs on 2 separate physical drives within the same PC.

**Background**: i am a curious person, so i may open files or visit sites for which i am not 100% certain that they are trustworthy. But i am also a little paranoid. Of course the most secure option is to use a separate PC, which does not contain any sensitive data or information for anything that's not 100% trustworthy. This option i do not have anymore at the moment, however I do got a spare HDD.

So, i was wondering how secure, in terms of viruses and other malicious software, a setup with two operating systems (win10/win7) would be, if (a) they would be used in a standard dual boot setup vs. (b) installed on separate drives. Is (b) actually safer? Is there any real risk of malicious code infecting between OSs? 
Does encryption of the drives with BitLocker make sense anyway, with the primary concern being a "spillover" from one OS to the other?

**VM side note**: I read about some safety limitations of dual boot setups compared to VMs - although it seemed that there were arguments for both? In any case, i deliberately ignored the VM option due to performance limitations of the VM option (e.g. lack of GPU hardware acceleration; afaik).

**How to**: Besides the safety question, i was also wondering whether the process would indeed be as simple as installing the second OS on the second drive, as usual, but while the first drive is unplugged (i read this here), and then select which drive to boot from in the BIOS's boot order? Would you need to disable UEFI every time you'd want to boot the win7 OS?

Besides your answers/suggestions, i am of course also grateful for relevant links. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualization and Gaming topics hardly go together. If you choose virtualization, you get stronger safety but poorer performance which is bad for gaming. If you choose dualboot, you get full performance but far poorer in term of safety. GPU passthrough for VM is theoretically possible but I guess it's not worth the trouble.

I've gone through the same decision you're facing. Here's what I suggest. Install one OS as secure environment on one hard disk, and another OS on another hard disk for less secured environment (gaming). You'll need a hardware that's called "front-rack" or "mobile-rack" or "hotswap" to easily plug and unplug hard disk without opening computer case every time. Only plug one hard disk at a time that you want to use. This should provide full performance that you want for gaming without compromising the secure environment. However remember that malware can spread over network and reinfect your secure environment when it's booted up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a particular reason you would go with the hardware solution rather than the boot-order solution? Is it a safety or stability concern? Was also wondering whether there's a risk that the OSs mess with each other without literally disconnecting the non-used drive.
Is there actually useful hardware modules or something for your suggested "front-rack" option without completely switching the case? Like 3.5" mounts?

Comment: Without physically disconnecting one hard disk, yes, there's a risk that one OS can compromise another, even they're in different disks. By compromising, it could be malware spreading, altering or destroying data by overwriting it. It's all depend how severe the malware is, which you couldn't know or even predict. Hiding or unmounting another drive in OS can give "some" protection but I suggest not to rely on it if you face with sophisticated malware. If you can hide or unmount programmatically, malware writer can also revert that. Front-rack makes use of CD/DVD drive opening as hdd rack.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was wondering just now whether there are (external) switches that depending on their state can be used to supply power to one of the two drives only - seems simpler than disconnecting the drive and should have the same effect. Anyone an idea what type of equipment could be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a VM. The VM advantages outweight the dualboot system by far.

1. Its way easier and more convenient to actually work with vitual machines. If you want to access data from the other OS, you have to reboot your dualboot system each time. Thats very annoying and you can eliminate this problem by using a VM
2. Its really easy to intall and reinstall an Virtual OS you dont have to worry about bootloader and stuff like that. Your vitrualizationtool will do everything for you.
3. You have the advantage of taking snapshots of your virtual system. So if you really got a virus on your VM, just skip back to a snapshot you took before the infection. problem solved.
4. And yes there are even more security advantages of VMs. for more information about this I would visit this question: [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/is-dual-booting-an-os-more-or-less-secure-than-running-a-virtual-machine)
5. If you have about 8GB of RAM its no problem to run 2 virtual Windows10 Systems in addition to your host Windows. Here a discussion about that: [tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/39176-how-much-ram-should-i-have-smoothly-run-virtual-machine.html)

So basicly what I want to say is: use a virtual machine. Its just more convenient an practically.
I hope my answer helps you for your decision.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that in principle a VM is preferable, however my main reason for considering the alternative option is the performance issue. I never dealt with VMs in much detail, but for the bit of experience i have, it seems that GPU pass-through does not (reliably?) work on a windows host; correct?

Comment: Well, I have never worked with GPU passtrough. And my short research detremined, that GPU passtrough is in fact not possible on a windows host.  But at this point you could consider a Linux system as host and then virtualize both of your Windows and make your pass troughs there. You could build something like this [Setting up a Windows VM with GPU passthrough](https://me.m01.eu/blog/2015/09/windows-vm-gpu-passthrough/)  Im not 100% shure if you have enough ressources to run a Linux as host and 2 virtualized Windwos with GPU passthroug. What are your PC specs?

Comment: My PC specs are decent enough for the most part, but of course that solution will still tank performance (somewhat) and i was actually considering going the Linux as host route before, but never really could rid myself of wanting windows as default OS. And taking this a step further, i.e. running dual boot Win/Linux to then run a virtualized win under a Linux host seems like over-kill. Hehe. So, I may just stick withhe 2 drives method. Thanks a lot for ideas nonetheless!